# Destructible tiles in unity's tilemap

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm creating a 2d game and I want to make it so that tiles are destructible whenever a projectile collides with a tile. The problem is I don't know how to get the tile that the projectile is colliding with, I would like to make it so that it area of damage.

However for now I want to make it so that once the projectile reaches the ground it destroys the tile it's sitting on I've made a collider2d to help me with that but I still have no idea how to get the tile that's the projectile is sitting on.

```
IEnumerator OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{ 
    //Projectile has reached the ground and is in collision with some tile
    Vector2 hit = gameObject.transform.position;
    Debug.Log("y" + hit.y);
    hit.y =- 3; // i have no idea what y i should put in order to get the tile

    if (x.gameObject.tag != "Player")
    {   
            Collider2D[] collidedwith = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(this.gameObject.transform.position, radius);
            //what should the hit vector be in order to destroy the tile.
            tilemap.SetTile(tilemap.WorldToCell(hit), null);  
    }
}
```

A screenshot for better explanation (I would like to get rid of the blue tile):

[image]

If possible I would like to make it into an aoe projectile but for now it's not necessary

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have colliders in place, that is:

- Collider in the rocket with `is trigger` selected (to allow `OnTriggerEnter2D` be triggered)
- Collider on the tiles to actually trigger the `OnTriggerEnter2D` of the rocket during the collision

Now, to detect collisions between rocket and tiles, do the following:

1. Give the tile gameObject (prefab) the `tag` name `tile`
2. Replace your code in the rocket with:

Script

```
// It will be triggered the the rocket crashes against the tile
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)
{
    if(collision.gameObject.tag == "tile")
    {
        // Destroy the tile the rockets collided with
        Destroy(collision.collider.gameObject);
        // Destroy the rocket itself
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

Comment: i have set everything as you said but it still doesn't work :/ i dont think you can just create a tile prefab when you are using tilemap

Comment: ok so i apparently fixed this, i will post an answer below if you have any idea how to make it so that the projectile does circular damage (destroys the 3 blocks around it) i would be really grateful

Answer (score 1):

ok i came up with a solution but this solution doesn't really have the feature i really wanted which is, i want the projectile to do aoe damage

```
    Tilemap tilemap = GetComponent<Tilemap>();
    Vector3 hitPosition = Vector3.zero;
    foreach (ContactPoint2D hit in collision.contacts)
    {
        Debug.Log(hit.point);
        hitPosition.x = hit.point.x - 0.1f;
        hitPosition.y = hit.point.y - 0.1f ;
        tilemap.SetTile(tilemap.WorldToCell(hitPosition), null);
    }
```